# PhoneGap / jQueryMobile: in iOS tapping select control jumps page back

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, icenium

I'm programming my first mobile app using Icenium, PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile.

I have several select elements on different pages.

[image]

In Android it is working like expected. But in iOS and Icenium's iOS simulator, it is not. When you tap the element, you see in a fraction that it opens the options like a regular HTML option list and than it jumps immediately back to the previous page.

I have no errors and I don't know where to start to find the solution. I have search on Google, but no one does seem to have this kind of problem.

The html is looking like this:

```
<label class="cornerlogospan" for="ddlLanguage">Language</label>
<select class="settingselectfield" id="ddlLanguage" data-bind="value: Settings().UILanguage">
    <option value="nl">Dutch</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
</select>
```

Generated html:

```
<label class="cornerlogospan">Language:</label>
<div class="ui-select">
<div id="ddlLanguage-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <span class="settingselectfield">English</span>
    <select class="settingselectfield" id="ddlLanguage" data-bind="value: Settings().UILanguage">
        <option value="nl">Dutch</option>
        <option value="fr">French</option>
        <option value="en">English</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Edit**
After the suggestion of Omar, I did add the  `data-native-menu="false"` attribute. The page doesn't change anymore, but the page doesn't change anymore. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szVv2QfSH9M I still can't select a language. This is also the case in Android now.

Comment: `data-native-menu="false"`? pls add more details.

Comment: if you remove `data-bind` does the same occur?

Comment: @Omar Yes, the same problem occurs.

Comment: weird. add `data-native-menu="false"`, it will be converted into a popup. just to check if the same happens.

Comment: The jump to the previous page isn't occuring anymore with that. I have made a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szVv2QfSH9M The second dropdown doesn't have the `data-native-menu="false"`

Comment: language select is normal, size is `native="false"` right?

Comment: No, the other way around. Language select is with attribute `data-native-menu="false"`. Size doesn't has this attribute added.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46328/discussion-between-omar-and-jurgenstillaert)

Comment: I have found the problem. An onclick action was misplaced. Android wasn't caring about it, iOS was more strict.